# Pseudo-elements are working in Chrome but not in Opera or Firefox

Tags: firefox, opera, pseudo-element

I'm trying to convert a PSD file to a working HTML template but am facing a problem while working on pseudo-elements.

Check out this page: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50181101/Planetabhi/index.html

I have used an image with `:after` & `:before` for "Latest Blog Post"; `line.png` is only showing in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox & Opera.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using `::after` and `::before` with two colons? That’s the right syntax for them, really, although one colon should work.

Comment: Yea I have already tried it. but no changes.